# Steps needed to make Google action available in other countries?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We currently have an action live in the US which is backed by an English agent in api.ai.  What steps, if any, need to be taken to make this available in other English speaking countries as Google Home is made available in more countries? (e.g. Australia, Canada, UK, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Actions are currently only supported in the US. Once we are ready to support other countries, we will update our console, documentation and samples to help developers.